# SQL Server Row by Row Access

Tags: sql-server, row-level-security

I have a table structured as so (Simplified)

```
Name, EMail, LastLoggedInAt
```

I have a user in SQL Server (RemoteUser) that should only be able to see data (Via a select query) where the LastLoggdInAt field is not null.

It looks like I can do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The SQL Server security model allows you to grant access to a view without granting access to the underlying tables.

Since example code is a great way to show a concept, consider the following, with a `LoginDetails` table, and corresponding view:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LoginDetails
(
    Username nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
    , EmailAddress nvarchar(256) NOT NULL
    , LastLoggedInAt datetime NULL
);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.LoginDetailsView
AS
SELECT ld.Username
    , ld.EmailAddress
    , ld.LastLoggedInAt
FROM dbo.LoginDetails ld
WHERE ld.LastLoggedInAt IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

We'll create a login, and a user, then assign that user the rights to select rows from the view, without having any rights to view the table itself.

```
CREATE LOGIN RemoteUser 
WITH PASSWORD = '2q1345lkjsadfgsa0(*';

CREATE USER RemoteUser
FOR LOGIN RemoteUser
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.LoginDetailsView TO RemoteUser;
```

Now, we'll insert two test rows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.LoginDetails(Username, EmailAddress, LastLoggedInAt)
VALUES ('user x', 'x@y.com', NULL)
    , ('user y', 'y@y.com', GETDATE());
```

This tests the security model.  The first `SELECT` statement succeeds, since it is selecting from the view, whereas the second `SELECT` statement fails because the user does not have direct access to the table.

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'RemoteUser';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.LoginDetailsView;
```

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Username ║ EmailAddress ║     LastLoggedInAt      ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ user y   ║ y@y.com      ║ 2018-02-15 07:36:54.490 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LoginDetails;

REVERT
```

Note the results from the view exclude the row where the `LastLoggedInAt` value is `NULL`, as required in your question.

The second `SELECT` statement against the underlying table returns an error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 28
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'LoginDetails', database 'tempdb', schema 'dbo'.

Cleanup:

```
DROP USER RemoteUser;
DROP LOGIN RemoteUser;
DROP VIEW dbo.LoginDetailsView;
DROP TABLE dbo.LoginDetails;
```

---

Alternately, if you have SQL Server 2016 or newer, you could use a row-level-security-predicate to prevent certain users seeing rows with a NULL `LastLoggedInAt` value.  The Microsoft Docs for Row Level Security is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security).

First, we create the table, a login, a user for that login, and we grant access to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LoginDetails
(
    Username nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
    , EmailAddress nvarchar(256) NOT NULL
    , LastLoggedInAt datetime NULL
);
GO

CREATE LOGIN RemoteUser 
WITH PASSWORD = '2q1345lkjsadfgsa0(*';

CREATE USER RemoteUser
FOR LOGIN RemoteUser
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.LoginDetails TO RemoteUser;
```

Next, we insert a couple of sample rows.  One row with a null `LastLoggedInAt`, and one with a non-null value for that column.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.LoginDetails(Username, EmailAddress, LastLoggedInAt)
VALUES ('user x', 'x@y.com', NULL)
    , ('user y', 'y@y.com', GETDATE());
```

Here, we're creating a schema-bound table-valued-function that returns a row with either 0 or 1 depending on the value of the `@LastLoggedInAt` and `@username` variables that are passed into the function.  This function will be used by a filter-predicate to eliminate the rows we want to hide from certain users.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_LoginDetailsRemoteUserPredicate
(
    @LastLoggedInAt datetime
    , @username sysname
)  
RETURNS TABLE  
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS fn_securitypredicate_result   
    WHERE (@username = N'RemoteUser' AND @LastLoggedInAt IS NOT NULL)
        OR @username <> N'RemoteUser';  
GO
```

This is the security filter that eliminates rows from `SELECT` statements ran against the `dbo.LoginDetails` table:

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY LoginDetailsRemoteUserPolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.fn_LoginDetailsRemoteUserPredicate(LastLoggedInAt, USER_NAME())
ON dbo.LoginDetails
WITH (STATE=ON);
```

The filter above uses the `dbo.fn_LoginDetailsRemoteUserPredicate` function by passing in the name of the current user, along with the values from each row for the `LastLoggedInAt` column from the `dbo.LoginDetails` table.

If we query the table as a normal user:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LoginDetails
```

we see all rows:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Username ║ EmailAddress ║     LastLoggedInAt      ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ user x   ║ x@y.com      ║ NULL                    ║
║ user y   ║ y@y.com      ║ 2018-02-15 13:53:42.577 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

However, if we test as the `RemoteUser`:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'RemoteUser';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.LoginDetails

REVERT
```

we only see "valid" rows:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Username ║ EmailAddress ║     LastLoggedInAt      ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ user y   ║ y@y.com      ║ 2018-02-15 13:42:02.023 ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

And, we clean up:

```
DROP SECURITY POLICY LoginDetailsRemoteUserPolicy;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_LoginDetailsRemoteUserPredicate;
DROP USER RemoteUser;
DROP LOGIN RemoteUser;
DROP TABLE dbo.LoginDetails;
```

Be aware that schema-binding a function to the table in this way does make it impossible to modify the definition of the table without first dropping the filter predicate, and the `dbo.fn_LoginDetailsRemoteUserPredicate` function.